# BadSqlGrammarException when Spring Batch inserts into BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION

Tags: db2, spring-batch

I am creating a spring-batch application which reads from a CSV file and writes into a DB2 database.

Spring-boot version : 2.0.5.RELEASE

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
    <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
    <version>db2jcc4</version>
</dependency>
```

I am getting an BadSqlGrammarException when Spring Batch tries to insert into the BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION table.

> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, JOB_INSTANCE_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, VERSION, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED, JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, 
>   SQLERRMC=JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION, DRIVER=4.26.14Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, JOB_INSTANCE_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, VERSION, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED, JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION, DRIVER=4.26.14

Thanks in advance for any kind of support and direction that helps in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION
```

From [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/codes/src/tpc/db2z_sqlstatevalues.html), SQLSTATE 42703 means `An undefined column or parameter name was detected` . So it is most probably due to the `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION` does not have `JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION` column.

Make sure your batch related tables have the schema that are the same as [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-db2.sql).

Comment: Hi Ken Chan,
The tables were created but the column JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION was missing.

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Update: column JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION is [no longer needed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#all-platforms) needed after Spring Batch 5.0.

Comment: Just to underscore, be sure to get the DDLs from the sql schema in the source code (link posted by Ken Chan) rather than from the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index-single.html#metaDataSchema), which are not always reliable.